Error on SMBCALCS "NT_STATUS_INVALID_OWNER"
I am trying to change permissions using command line from SMBCALCS to a Windows share. I have checked the the user has the proper permissions and the permissions setting works using the --set command, but not when using --modify or --add.
I get an error
ERROR: security descriptor set failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_OWNER

The command I am running is:
smbcacls //<IP ADDRESS>/<SHARE> /Data/Folder/Folder --add='ACL:DOMAIN\GroupName:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL' -A /etc/smb/creds --propagate-inheritance


Did you get this to work without changing the owner?

I got around this by setting ownership on the folder to the service account I was running smbcacls with.

So the user running SMBCACLS has Full Control permissions, they should be able to change the permissions. Is there any way to get this to work without having to change the owner?
